# どこに住んでも and どこに住むのも difference

Tags: word-choice

I heard in a movie 何処に住むのも自由 and I wonder what's the difference with どこに住んでも自由 ?

I think nominalizer の + も is more formal but not sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think.

何処に住むのも自由。

**You are free to choose where you live.**

何処に住んでも自由。

**Wherever you live, you are free.**